# Progress bar not updating in Win32

Tags: visual-studio-2010, winapi, visual-c++, timer

I create a Progress bar in Win32 and it does not update when I'm building the application in Release configuration but works in the Debug configuration. The progress bar is created as follows:

```
progBar= CreateWindowEx(0,PROGRESS_CLASS,NULL,WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE|PBS_SMOOTH,rc.right/2-130,rc.bottom/2, 260, 17,hWnd, NULL, hInst, NULL);

        //Sets the range of progress bar
        SendMessage(progBar, PBM_SETRANGE, 0, MAKELPARAM(0,10));    //0->min value; 10->max value
        SetTimer(hWnd, TIMER_1, 1000, TimerProc);                   //set the timer
```

and my TimerProc is :

```
void CALLBACK TimerProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, UINT idEvent, DWORD dwTime)
{

switch(msg)
{
    case WM_TIMER:
    {
        SendMessage(progBar, PBM_SETPOS,stepValue,0);       //stepValue
        InvalidateRect(progBar,NULL,TRUE);

        if(stepValue>9)
        {
            stepValue=0;
        }

        else
        {
            stepValue++;
        }
    }
  }
  return;
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2010.Is it possible I'm missing some library since it works in Debug configuration. The runtime library I've selected is Multi-threaded (/MT)

Comment: Try to debug Release configuration. From the code here I can only think about uninitialized stepValue variable, but debugger can tell you more.

Comment: Delete the InvalidateRect() call and ensure stepValue is initialized.  Use the debugger.  And just don't do it this way, this is already supported with the PBM_SETMARQUEE message.

Comment: `WM_TIMER` messages are low priority. They are generated only if the message queue is empty. Have you verified that `WM_TIMER` messages are created in a Release build?

Comment: Yes ,im getting the wm_timer measage. I had kept breakpoints and the stepvalue gets incremented as well.@hans: I have initialized the stepvalue to 0. But how is it that the same code worls fine for debug builds? This used to work perfectly before, dont know what I changed in between

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Hans I tried the Marquee style progress bar and it worked. The code change will be as follows:

```
        progBar= CreateWindowEx(0,PROGRESS_CLASS,NULL,WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE|PBS_MARQUEE,rc.right/2-130,rc.bottom/2, 260, 17,hWnd, NULL, hInst, NULL);

        SendMessage(progBar, PBM_SETMARQUEE,TRUE,50);
```

and I removed the SetRange statement.According to this link

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/407cf8d0-02cc-4276-adb1-3fc619ce4f3a/progress-bar-with-marquee-style

I had to add

```
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

else the Marquee progress bar would not work. Could some one explain this? But this works for me on Release builds as well.